# Button in JavaScript is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

An error message appeared after adding my button which calls a function in JavaScript. I cannot find the problem.

Sorry for the faults. I am French and I'm using Google Translate.

Here is the part of the code in question:

```
document.getElementById("jouer").onclick = start();
document.getElementById("jouer").onclick = function () { alert('defis[0]'); };

<input id= "jouer " type="button" value="jouer" click="start()"/>;
```

And the error message is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to run both JS and HTML in one file.

To get it to work, you need to create a separate file with HTML stuff and use
`<script src="your-js-file.js"></script>` in the HTML file for the browser to be able to run JS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function start() {
  alert('i am working')
};

document.getElementById('jouer2').onclick = start
```

```html
<input id= "jouer " type="button" value="jouer" onclick="start()"/>;
<input id= "jouer2" type="button" value="jouer2"/>;
```

```
target.onclick = functionRef;
```

functionRef is a function name or a function expression. so you can try this
`document.getElementById("jouer").onclick = start;`
also you don't need the `click` attribute in the element as you are targeting the DOM element above. if you want to trigger a function directly from some element then pass `onclick` attribute with the function call and you won't need  to target like this
`document.getElementById("jouer").onclick`
reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: i assume you put your JS code in `<script>` tag or in separate js file

Comment: my js code is in a <script> tag in the same folder I tried to put it in a .js folder but it gives me the same error

Comment: did you try this? `document.getElementById("jouer").onclick = start;`

Comment: yes I have tried the 2 version

Comment: ok i am giving you a working example

Comment: run the snippet. see both version are working.

Answer (score 0):

The only error i see is that you have a whitspace in the id selector in the input `"jouer"`. this causes the script to not be able to grab the element. Otherwise, the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` means that you are trying to include a file (script) that it can't find.